# Were there any successful revolutions that didn't end in a totalitarian regime?

Tags: revolution

By revolution, I mean a violent overthrow of a system of government, from *within* the country itself. So, the American Revolution doesn't count for my question, since it was a revolution to push out an external power. Specifically, I'm drawing a line between revolutions that wanted to destroy an existing government, and revolutions that wanted to create a new government independent of the one it was under. What would count would be the French Revolution, Russian Revolution, Cuban revolution, etc. I realize this isn't the general definition of "revolution," but it's the type of revolution that I'm particularly interested in.

Ideally, the revolution would be more populist in nature. The French revolution of 1848 seems like a decent example, but I'd still like to know if there were others.

In essence, this is the thesis I hope to see disproved:

*Violent, populist revolutions that seek to completely depose an existing form of government end in totalitarian/authoritarian/tyrannical regimes.*

EDIT: I've narrowed my question slightly, and tightened the definitions I was using. My apologies for under specifying the question in the beginning, I hope that as it stands this question can be answered.

Comment: The answer is trivially yes, because there are too many instances of such: Foundation of the Roman Republic. Reforms of Draco and then Solon in Athens followed a period of widespread civil unrest that would seem to be a revolution". "*Glorious Revolution" of 1688 in Great Britain. French Revolution of 1848. Unification of Italy. I would even argue that the Reconquista in Spain, though it took centuries, was one such. Likewise the Eighty Years War of liberation in the Netherlands - as the very concept of *nationalisim* that you use to eliminate the American Revolution is post-Napoleonic concept

Comment: Independence of Belgium in the 1830's from the Netherlands. Overthrow of the German Monarchies in 1919 leading to formation of the Weimar Republic. Poland probably has a few (maybe more) examples, but I don't know Polish history well enough of the top of my head to list them.

Comment: Do you consider modern Russia a "totalitarian regime"?  Do you consider the [velvet revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velvet_Revolution) pushing out a foreign power?  Also, most people in the American Colonies prior to 1775 would have found the idea that Britain was a "foreign power" entirely shocking.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess my question was misguided. Still, the Glorious Revolution ended in a monarchy, which at least for me isn't much better, I was more looking for populist revolutions, but that's on me for not specifying. The independence of Belgium didn't overthrow the government of the Netherlands, it was for independence, so that doesn't count.

Comment: And I think there's a well defined distinction between independence and internal revolution - one aims to leave the current government in place and creates a new one, and the other aims to replace it.  Maybe I've used the wrong words, I'm not a historian, but I think the concepts I'm concerned with are more well defined than you're giving me credit for.

Comment: @ThatGuy: No-one here is a mind reader - we know your intent ***only to the extent you lay it clearly, with semantic definitions as necessary***. All non-trivial assertions must also be supported with evidence.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens totally understand, I'm sorry if I seemed accusatory, I wasn't trying to. I understand the question was under-specified, I've tried to edit it and I hope it's clearer what I mean now. I suspected it would be when I posted it, I just didn't know what the areas of contention would be.

Comment: The revolutions against the communist states in Eastern Europe and Russia were about as populist as you can get.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. My (very possibly incorrect) understanding was that the revolutions that toppled the Soviet union were mostly non-violent. Is that not correct?

Comment: Sorry, missed the part about violent, though there was certainly violence in Russia and some of the former Warsaw Pact states.  (Particularly Romania)

Comment: and the US revolutionary war...

Comment: Can you clarify what constitutes 'violent'? Do there have to be 10s, 100s or 1000s of deaths? There are also cases where there is some violence but few or no deaths.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Is the idea of violence so poorly defined that we need to provide an exact number? I understand it's a spectrum, but surely we can discuss it in broad terms?

Comment: I'm OK with broad terms and I'm not looking for an exact number, but it would be useful if you could state that in your question because people have different ideas about this. Ultimately, it's your question so it's your criteria that need to be satisfied.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Ah okay, fair enough. In that case I confess that I'm not sure. I suppose any amount would satisfy me, as long as the answer is in good faith. I feel a little like I've accidentally wandered into a minefield here, and I'm trying to orient myself to figure out why my question was so poorly received.

Comment: The problem with a question like this is, I think, that you have to be very careful and clear with the details and terms. You're right, it is bit of a minefield but I hope it will stay open as it is basically a good question.

Comment: re: "revolutions that wanted to create a new government independent of the one it was under" - could the first section, where you define what kind of revolution you mean, be streamlined to "excluding separatist movements"? When successful, these do tend to be called "revolutions" by their beneficiaries, but it isn't quite the same process.

Comment: Also, wouldn't a "revolution that is not populist" be more correctly defined as a coup? If the political party does not have a power base in masses, to pull off a succesful revolution it would need some other kind of power base, and usually it would mean military support.

Answer (score 4):

Examples are abundant, beginning with the "Glorious revolution" in England. July revolution 1830 in France, overthrow of the Communist regime in Roumania, the Ukrainian revolution of 2014. All these were violent overthrows of the governments which did not lead to a totalitarian regime. There were also many non-violent revolutions, and many "in between". For example the February 1917 revolution in Russia was non-violent, violence started later, and it did not establish a totalitarian regime.  (Totalitarian regime was established in November 1917, but this is considered another revolution by most historians).

Comment: the Russian invasion of Ukraine in 2014 was not a revolution, it was a foreign invasion.

Comment: I was not talking of Russian invasion. Ukrainian revolution overthrew the president, was violent, but did not lead to establishment of totalitarian state.

Comment: Okay, I suppose this mostly answers the question, thank you. I will research these events more. Though, I feel that's a bit of a technicality with the Russian revolution. I agree there's a spectrum between what can and cannot be considered a consequence of the revolution, but for the purposes of discussing the effects of a revolution 8 months hardly seems like long enough to discount it.

Comment: @ThatGuy: Yes, Russian revolution(s) of 1917 are questionable in many respects. The most difficult question is whether the November revolution was an inevitable consequence of the February revolution. But this is undecidable.

Answer (score 3):

**The Carnation Revolution**

Many good examples have already been provided, but I would add the [Carnation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnation_Revolution) Revolution in 1974 in Portugal, that overthrew Salazar's authoritarian Estado Nuovo and [resulted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_transition_to_democracy) in the Republic of Portugal.

Comment: This seems like a good example to me. Would this be an example of a revolution that could be considered violent, despite the fact there were relatively few dead, such as Lars Bosteen referenced?

Comment: @ThatGuy It depends of the degree of violence you are looking for. The Carnation Revolution was certainly not a bloodbath (4 deaths are recorderd during the first coup on 25th of april 1974), but it led to 2 years of instability (including the "hot summer" of 1945) with sporadic fights before the new Consitution and the elected government took full control.

Comment: *1975, not 1945

Answer (score 0):

The English revolution that pitted the Crown against parliament with the final settlement we see today, a constitutional monarchy where parliament is sovereign.

I’d dispute that the American Revolution was about pushing out a foreign power. They were - after all - a British colony - and more broadly, a European colony.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130119/discussion-on-answer-by-mozibur-ullah-were-there-any-successful-revolutions-that).